# What happens when you use the same fixture twice, explicitly and implicitly at the same time?

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

I have a function that is using a couple of fixture 'session_id' and 'set_namespace'. I recently noticed that 'set_namespace' fixture is using 'session_id' fixture itself.
both of the fixtures scope is set to session.
Does it mean i'll get a different result in each fixture?

my code:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def session_id():
    return random_id(length=5)


@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def set_namespace(request, session_id, load_config):
    some_dict['namespace'] = session_id


def some_function(session_id, set_namespace):
    does_something
```

Comment: print the session ID and find out?

Comment: I have, it's the same ID though I would like to know how it works.

Answer (score 2):

No, you would get the same session ID because pytest would ensure that each fixture is called only certain number of times depending on the `scope` set. Just because one fixture uses another fixture doesn't change this principle. What exactly happens in what order can be displayed using the `--setup-show` flag.

#### Tests code

```py
# tests/test.py
from uuid import uuid4

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def session_id():
    return str(uuid4())

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def set_namespace(session_id):
    return {"id": session_id}

def test_a(session_id, set_namespace):
    print("\n", session_id, set_namespace, sep="\n")

def test_b(session_id, set_namespace):
    print("\n", session_id, set_namespace, sep="\n")
```

#### Result

`$ pytest --setup-show ./tests/test.py`:

```
SETUP    S session_id
SETUP    S set_namespace (fixtures used: session_id)
        tests/test.py::test_a (fixtures used: session_id, set_namespace)

6d3c5d86-4aee-4372-8167-f9c811e69cdc
{'id': '6d3c5d86-4aee-4372-8167-f9c811e69cdc'}
.
        tests/test.py::test_b (fixtures used: session_id, set_namespace)

6d3c5d86-4aee-4372-8167-f9c811e69cdc
{'id': '6d3c5d86-4aee-4372-8167-f9c811e69cdc'}
.
TEARDOWN S set_namespace
TEARDOWN S session_id
```

**Note**: pytest also has `--setup-plan` flag which doesn't execute anything but that IMHO doesn't take into account scopes and thus displays incorrect order.